# Find the first fork from a commit in Git

Tags: git

Consider the following Git history

```
              o-----A
o-----o-----B/-------\o--------o-------o----->>
```

I need to find the first ancestor of A that is a fork point.
In this case it's B.

I've tried use merge-base, log or rev-list command.

These commands all assume that we want to know the common ancestor of two commit or two references.

In my case I just know A and need to know what's the first fork point of its history.

EDIT: The context of that request is that I'm migrating tools from mercurial. Mercurial has named branches which make easy to find the branch fork point.
It seems that it's not possible to retreive the same information with Git.
In spite of this the @jthill answer is the closest from the original request

Comment: Actually i search for something like rev-list but where I can specify 'only commits with multiple childs'

Comment: Why would you like it? The term "first" is ambiguous. By date or by log graph depth? In some cases the first commit with multiple childs may not be what you want.

Comment: result can depend on which branch you fork from

Comment: @elpiekay actually i'm migrating tools from mercurial. One of the tools needs the change that correspond to the branche creation. The "named branches" of mercurial make it easy but reading your comments makes me realize that there's no equivalent with Git branches.

Comment: Commits aren't associated with branch names in git because branch names are _strictly_ local  -- any correspondence between multiple repos is a matter of coincidence or mutual agreement  It's the history's ancestry structure that matters, not what anybody calls it.  What are you going to do with this information you're after?  Ask about what you want, not just about how to implement the method you've chosen to get what you want.

Comment: some tools which do mercurial to git migration keep the branch name in migrated message commit, you could use that

Comment: Yep we're using hggit right now to keep  user workflow on hg and remote on git. It stores branch information in commit messages. I'll try to handle this way or i'll discard the feature as it's not critical (it's for formatting release message automatically, we check if we come from a version branch to indicate it in the message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which commit you'd call 'first" in this picture:

[image: commits]

it could be "c" if you treat N as your mainline. merge-base gives you "b2" but probably this not what you need

Answer (score 2):

```
git rev-list --all --children | awk 'NF>2 {print $1}' >bases
git rev-list A | grep -m1 -Ff bases
```

Comment: Thx for the answer @jthill but i forgot to mention that i'm working on windows. If possible i'd to find a pure git solution but i'll keep it if nothing else is proposed :)

Comment: git's not meant to be "pure", it's meant to be a tool in your toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

The fork point of branch1 and branch2:
`git merge-base branch1 branch2`

The fork point of current branch and another branch (e.g., master):
`git merge-base --fork-point master`